# Why am i having "Cannot read property 'http' of undefined" on this validator?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im trying to make an asynchronous validator for a reactive form control, that checks if a given username already exists. Heres's the async validator code:

**userdata.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserdataService {

   private apiUrl = 'http://apiurl.com/api'; // its not the real url, im just not posting it for privacy reasons

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


   checkUsername(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {

    let isUsernameValid;
    return new Promise<any>(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/users?name='+control.value).subscribe(
          response => {
            isUsernameValid = response;
        });
        if (isUsernameValid === 'false') {
          resolve({'usernameIsInvalid': true})
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      }
    );
  }

}
```

When I try this validator i get this error:
"core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined"

Now, i think the errr has something to do with using 'this' but I can't understand why isn't working...
It was driving me insane so I tryed to just place a

```
console.log(this.apiUrl)
```

inside the function, outside the promise, just for the sake of trying, and i had the same error: "core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'apiUrl' of undefined"...

Please if someone can explain to me what am I doing wrong, and how to solve it i would be thankful.

**EDIT:**

I'm calling my service from the reactive form ts file, as shown below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomValidatorsService } from '../services/custom-validators.service';
import { LocationService } from '../services/location.service';
import { UserdataService } from '../services/userdata.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-userdata-form',
  templateUrl: './userdata-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userdata-form.component.scss']
})
export class UserdataFormComponent implements OnInit {

  userdataForm: FormGroup;
  provinces: any = null;
  provincesLoading = false;
  cities: any = null;
  citiesLoading = false;

  constructor(
    private locationService: LocationService,
    private userdataService: UserdataService,
    private customValidators: CustomValidatorsService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formInit();
    this.loadProvinces();
  }

  formInit() {

    let dni: number = null;
    let firstname: string = null;
    let lastname: string = null;
    let email: string = null;
    let mobile: number = null;
    let phone: number = null;
    let birthdate: Date = null;
    let username: string = null;
    let password: string = null;

    this.userdataForm = new FormGroup({

        // ... a lot of controls before ...

        'username': new FormControl(username, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3),
          Validators.maxLength(30),
          Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+$/)
        ], this.userdataService.checkUsername), // <-- here's the async validator

        // ... form continues...

  }

  loadProvinces() {
    this.provincesLoading = true;
    this.locationService.getProvinces().subscribe(response => {
      this.provinces = response;
      this.provincesLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you create an instance of this class and passed some parameter to assign http variable ?

Comment: Can you verify that the code you've pasted here matches the current code that you have? How exactly are you using the service?

Comment: edited the post to reflect the complete code.. some parts (like other controls) are not included because they are irrelevant to the subject

Comment: You'll have to create an async validator (i.e. a validator that implements the [`AsyncValidator`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator) interface), not a service: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#implementing-a-custom-async-validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, your custom validator should implement the [`AsyncValidator`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator) interface:

```js
import { AbstractControl, AsyncValidator, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
// ...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserDataValidator implements AsyncValidator {

  private apiUrl = 'http://apiurl.com/api'; // its not the real url, im just not posting it for privacy reasons

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  // This method is defined as an arrow function such that it can be used
  // properly - see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24981
  validate = (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/users?name=${control.value}`).pipe(
      map(isUsernameValid => (isUsernameValid === 'false' ? { usernameIsInvalid: true } : null),
      catchError(() => of(null))
    );
  }

}
```

This can then be added to your `FormGroup` as follows:

```js
constructor (private userDataValidator: UserDataValidator) {
  this.userdataForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl(username, [
      // ... validators
      // Validator classes don't currently work - see
      // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24981
      this.userDataValidator.validate
    ]),
    // ... other form controls
}
// ...
```

---

#### Notes

- I've also cleaned up your code that does the validation logic to use [RxJS' pipeable operators](https://rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators) as well as to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))
- Disclaimer: I've not tested that the code above actually works

---

#### Resources

- [Angular - Validating form input > Creating asynchronous validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#creating-asynchronous-validators)
- [Allow passing validator classes to the FormControl constructor · Issue #24981 · angular/angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24981)

Comment: Can you explain why can't my validator be a service?

Comment: @AgusDllano To be honest, I don't think there's anything wrong with it being a service - I was just following the documentation on custom validators.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create validator function which get service instance in argument, just like in this article:
https://medium.com/@tomaszsochacki/how-to-do-asynchronous-validator-in-angular-7-6e80243a874a

when you pass method like this

```
'username': new FormControl(username, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3),
          Validators.maxLength(30),
          Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+$/)
        ], this.userdataService.checkUsername),
```

`this` context in checkUsername method is missed

or you can do this:

```
'username': new FormControl(username, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3),
          Validators.maxLength(30),
          Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+$/)
        ], this.userdataService.checkUsername.bind(this.userdataService)),
```

bind in first argument pass 'this' context to method when it is called